# How to put column headers in each group inside dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I want to split data frame by group and put headers for each of them.

For example:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | A |
| c1 | c2 | c3 | group |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | B |
| c1 | c2 | c3 | group |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | C |

Maybe you can do it with the example below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "c1" = seq(1,5,1),
  "c2" = seq(1,5,1),
  "c3" = seq(1,5,1),
  "c4" = seq(1,5,1),
  "c5" = seq(1,5,1),
  "group" = c("A","A","B","B","C")
)
```

This group_split() function may help you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Comment: Try `df %>% group_split(group)`?

Comment: @TarJae The table shown above. Each group has a header.

Comment: @MartinGal It converts df to list.

Comment: You want one data.frame and every group has it's own header row? That doesn't make any sense since one column has to be of one type. Coverting it into a list of df is the right way.

Comment: @MartinGal That is partly true but each group will have a common header (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5), but it will be at the head of group. Like a dataframe within a dataframe.

Comment: What are you trying to do, why do you want this particular format? This sounds like a "How to display my data" - problem and not a "How to change my data.frame".

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
  gather("variable", "value", -group)
```

Comment: (1) `gather` is a bit outdated nowadays. Better use `pivot_longer` or `pivot_wider`. (2) Why does this answer the question?

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29667940)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
df <- data.frame(
  "c1" = seq(1,5,1),
  "c2" = seq(1,5,1),
  "c3" = seq(1,5,1),
  "c4" = seq(1,5,1),
  "c5" = seq(1,5,1),
  "group" = c("A","A","B","B","C")
) %>% group_by(group) 
gl<- group_split(df)
```

this should create a list `gl` with as many groups as in `df`

To name the elements of your `gl` list, (not sure this is what you mean by adding a header?), do :

```
names(gl) <- unique(df$group)
```